# Problem with HTML5 offline in mobile web app

Tags: iphone, html, safari, offline

I can't get offline mode in iphone mobile Safari to work.

I have included my cache manifest file in the root of my directory.

```
 <html lang="se" manifest="cache.manifest">
```

My cache.manifest looks like

```
  CACHE MANIFEST 

  CACHE:
  /images/background-iphonelines.png
  /images/acne.jpg
 /images/lisa.jpg
 /images/bruno.jpg
 /images/urban.jpg
 /shops/acne.html
 /shops/lisa.html
 /shops/bruno.html
 /shops/urban.html
 /shops/shops.css
  /style.css
  script.js
  guide.html

  NETWORK:
  *
```

I also included a .htaccess file in my root directory with the content

```
  AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
```

When I'm trying to open my app on my Iphone it still says "Can't open page" (or similar, have my page in swedish).

Does someone have any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your mark-up and cache file look fine, but if the site won't go off-line there's a problem with the cache. It only has to fail on one element, and the whole thing won't work. Have you tried debugging your cache file? This post will help:

[Jonathan Stark, Debugging HTML 5 Offline Application Cache](http://jonathanstark.com/blog/2009/09/27/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache/)

**Note** this won't tell you which asset causes the failure (if any), but it *will* tell you if your cache is working or not.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the script and i got some errors              online: yes, event: checking, status: uncached                online: yes, event: downloading, status: uncached             online: yes, event: progress, status: uncached                online: yes, event: error, status: uncached (prolly a syntax error in manifest) – So hmm. probably something in the manifest, but I can't see what

Comment: You need to check the paths, and make sure that they are correct—you have some values which are relative to the cache file, and some that could go wrong (e.g. `guide.html` and `/style.css`—are they definitely correct?)

Comment: Now they are downloading..But when I go offline I get following error          ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: This computer’s Internet connection appears to be offline.
queryLoader/js/queryLoader.jsFailed to load resource: This computer’s Internet connection appears to be offline. I don't even include these scripts on my page. I use geolocation though...

Comment: You say you're using geolocation, presumably that involves some code. And I would imagine that that code in turn is calling upon Google's CDN for jQuery, which is the URL you reference in your comment.

Comment: I could get rid of the ajax and queryLoader stuff. It was probably some old stuff still in my cache. I tested my application with both geolocation and not and it is still not working offling on my mobile Safari. Now I only get a Failed to load resource on favicon.ico - The URL can't be shown.

Comment: favicon.ico is a common one with mobile and desktop Safari as both look for it even if you haven't explicitly defined it in your mark-up. You will see this in web inspector when looking at your site, it has nothing to do with appcaches. Just create a favicon link (empty or not, your choice) in your HTML to get rid of that error.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a similar issue yesterday.  Try removing the CACHE: and just listing the items for the cache.  I found this by accident and it seems to now work on IOS for me.  Also, I added a comment field at the top to make sure I can invalidate the cache.  I would give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. I included the lines below in the `cache.manifest` file & it fixed for me.

```
NETWORK:

*
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling for 2 hours with this and finally I've managed it! HORAY! I've added "/" to cache, this was the problem...

Comment: where did you add this?